# TypeScript: difference between function types

Tags: function, types, typescript

What's the formal difference between the types of these two variables in TypeScript?

```
var randomStringId = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
function randomStringId2() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
}
```

`randomStringId` has type `() => string`. `randomStringId2` has type `(): string`. Are they different? If yes, how? Or is it just my IDE showing differently two types that are fundamentally the same?

Comment: To understand the lambda syntax : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Comment: You have to be careful as the first one is a variable holding a function, and the second one is a defined function itself.  ``randomStringId2`` can be used BEFORE its declaration, while ``randomStringId`` cannot.  This is pure JavaScript differences and since TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, it inherits this difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions are the same.
However, these two functions are not:

```
var getX = () => this.x

function getX() {
    return this.x
}
```

look at the generated js code:

```
var _this = this;
var getX = function () {
    return _this.x;
};

function getX() {
   return this.x;
}
```

The function defined with arrow notation `() =>` captures the reference to `this` when it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no difference in the *Types*. Both are exactly the same. They take nothing and return a string.

Here is the proof :

```
interface Foo1{
    foo:()=>string;
}
interface Foo2{
    foo():string;
}
var foo1:Foo1;
var foo2:Foo2;
foo1 = foo2 = foo1;
```

However there is a difference in the way they *behave*. To understand the need for a lambda function `()=>` : http://youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1